# JScrollPane not refreshing when button clicked

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have some code that get's data from a h2 dB and then displays it in a JScrollPane. I have added a button that should refresh the information but it isn't working.

This is my code:

Code that is used for the JPanel:

```
JPanel pList = new JPanel();
Component pListl = new JLabel("Here you can view  players. Searching and more data will be coming soon.");
pList.add(pListl,SwingConstants.CENTER);
tabbedPane.addTab("Player List",pList);
tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0,KeyEvent.VK_1);


JButton ref = new JButton("Refresh");
pList.add(ref); 

ref.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JScrollPane stable;
        try {
            stable = memlistpop(stat);
            pList.remove(stable);
            pList.add(stable);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pList, stable);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});     

JScrollPane stable = memlistpop(stat);
pList.add(stable);
```

And this is the memlistpop funcation:

```
public static JScrollPane memlistpop(Statement stat) throws SQLException{

         ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT id,name,level,xp,trophycount FROM avatars");


            JTable t = new JTable(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)){;

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                public boolean isCellEditable(int row,int column){
                    return false;
                  }

            };

            t.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
            JScrollPane stable = new JScrollPane (t);
            stable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            stable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 323));
            //add the table to the frame
            return stable;


    }
```

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Don't create a new `JTable`, simply modify the table model of the current table.  2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

You may add a layout manager before adding your objects.

If you want to clear the content of your panel, then:

```
panel.removeAll();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // or other layout managers, such as boxlayout, etc
panel.add(myobject); // in this case, pList.add(stable);
```

That is what I do for myself;

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep removing and adding components from a visible GUI. Instead you can just update the component in the scroll pane by using:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( someComponent );
```

If you ever do need to remove/add components to a visible GUI, then the basic code is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
panel.repaint();
```